# Capistrano not restarting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, restart

Capistrano is deploying cold, deploying updates and uploading the symlink fine. It will not however restart.

I notice that permission is denied on the /script/process/reaper file. I have found [a suggestion](http://www.mail-archive.com/capistrano@googlegroups.com/msg04485.html) implying the file needs updated permissions. Does anyone have experience with this?

```
Macintosh-5:barcoden fogonthedowns$ cap deploy:restart
  * executing `deploy:restart'
  * executing "/home/fogonthedowns/owens.fogonthedowns.com/current/script/process/reaper"
    servers: ["owens.fogonthedowns.com"]
Password: 
    [owens.fogonthedowns.com] executing command
 ** [out :: owens.fogonthedowns.com] sh: /home/fogonthedowns/owens.fogonthedowns.com/current/script/process/reaper: Permission denied
    command finished
failed: "sh -c \"/home/fogonthedowns/owens.fogonthedowns.com/current/script/process/reaper\"" on owens.fogonthedowns.com
Macintosh-5:barcoden fogonthedowns$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your deployment environment? With Passenger (Apache) I have something like:

```
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

As an updated answer, for Capistrano 3 running on Passenger here is what I currently do:

```
task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      # If your tmp folder does not exist yet, uncomment the 
      # line below to create it.
      # execute :mkdir, "#{File.join(current_path,'tmp')}"
      execute :touch, "#{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

They have their own support forums, maybe you should try there. http://groups.google.co.uk/group/capistrano/

Answer (score 0):

Rails 2.3 no longer ships with the old reaper scripts.
http://www.capify.org/index.php/How_to_use_Capistrano_with_Rails_2.3